# Is it correct to use multiple hyphens in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

"...it will secure local-authority-enabled-and-delivered housing."

I think it does but I'm not sure. If not, can someone explain why?

Thank you.

Comment: If you think you need that many hyphens you should rewrite your sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It is not incorrect, but it is very cumbersome. You could eliminate some of the hyphens without altering the meaning, but why do that when you can eliminate them altogether by rewriting the sentence:

> It will secure housing enabled and delivered by local authorities.